# How to work with a knowledgeable but condescending senior?

Tags: professionalism, behavior

My manager wants me to **challenge** a software architect who is **senior to the both of us** and who has a a history of reacting poorly to this, going so far as to push colleagues out of the team. **How can I approach this situation?**

I am a software developer in a team of 8 members which includes a senior software architect, who provides us instructions about designs. This is in a medium sized company in north America.

I am introverted in general and like to avoid conflicts. According to my manager, I perform adequately for my role and received bonus for my performance. He does however think there are times where I tend to follow the architect's decision despite having good ideas of my own. He wants me to challenge the architect more often in a respectful manner.

The architect is a lot more knowledgeable than me on theories of computer science. He is also hard working and timely in his responses. The issue is he is always condescending in his responses. Some examples:

- if I come with a question with two possible solutions to know his opinion, instead of sharing what he thinks is better, he would say "Did you read chapter 'x' on the book 'y' or this particular paper?". He would then preach for 5 minutes what a good software developer should know before actually giving his opinion.
- he objects to pull requests that he hasn't approved, finding trivial faults in 50 different places quoting some theories/concepts and blocking the request
- in our stand-ups, he interrupts when other people are talking and doesn't miss an opportunity to portray how smart he is
- he favours theoretical best practices over simple, functional designs despite this leading to frequent complaints from users

The **architect is above our manager** in the organisation and has a lot of power and is close with the higher-ups, so my manager avoids getting involved. I want to tread carefully after what happened to a couple of senior developers who previously tried to address this. The architect ganged up on them with another principal engineer ultimately forcing them to move to another team. They've actually invited me to join them but I like my current team, the technology and the work we do. I *would* like to establish a better balance in my interactions with the architect though, because I have undoubtedly learned a lot from him and study the topics he points me to in my own time.

**How can I navigate this situation effectively?**

Options that I could think are:

- Speak with the person (may make it better or worse for a narcissist)
- Speak with manager (might be labelled not a team-player)
- Speak with HR (probably requires more concrete misbehaviour)
- Move to another team (possible, but don't like the technologies so much)
- Move to another company
- Any other options is greatly appreciated

Comment: Welcome to The Workplace @rdown. I believe your question is on-topic here (as opposed to [ips.se]) but I see you've made it even longer. We recommend distilling questions down to the core, answerable question and then expanding or providing details/examples where needed. I'll make a first edit.

Comment: I've tried to improve this but it's still pretty long. You may want to cut more detail but at least the core question is at the top. The big point you buried in your post is that this architect is **senior to your manager**. So why is your manager telling you to challenge him when he himself doesn't do so? Or has your manager found a way to push back when needed without irking the architect? Have you discussed this with your manager?

Comment: @Lilienthal thank you for your edit, which made it a better read than before. I will look to shorten it further as you suggested. The manager

Comment: The manager said he sometimes follows the architect (SA) as well without fully agreeing, as the SA is regarded high in the organisation, so he understands why I am doing it. But he labelled it as an issue with my confidence, so wants me to work on it and speak up more. I have not asked why he does not do the push back himself, may be this is something I should speak next time.

Comment: It is not clear to me, what problem do you want to address. You are writing a lot about how the architect is not very likeable and offending you, but not much about how he is impeding your work (other than taking 5 minutes of your time by being preachy).
What is the concrete changes you would like to see in the senior's behaviour?

Comment: I am looking to know if there is a way to establish better mutual respect.

Comment: Is **challenge** really the word you want here? It sounds like you were simply told that you should voice your own ideas more often, not turn things into a pissing contest. Also, nothing that you said sounds "condescending", just someone with poor communication skills and too much passion for engineering. I think you might be attributing malice when there is none...

Comment: Also, how did the architect in question drive the others out? Most of this sounds less-than-tactful, but well within the range of normal, so the part about driving the other engineers out seems out of place to me. If it's more than just the other engineers not personally liking the architect, I think the details should be added to the post

Comment: @Mars I'd suggest you read through the edit again. I didn't change any of the content. All of this was in the original question. I only moved things around and summarised the main question and crucial points at the top. Also keep in mind that we default to taking the OP's interpretation, in this case that the architect's behaviour is across the line, unless there's good reason not to.

Comment: @Mars Those parts are moved, not removed. If you believe you can further improve the question please do so in an [edit]. I stand by mine.

Comment: @Mars No, your edits are final. But a good faith edit should be fine. If anyone or the OP takes issue with the new wording they are free to edit again after all.

Comment: @Lilienthal True, but TWP is often on HNQ. A key edit could result in a dozen answers that don't help OP and a thousand misplaced upvotes... That's the main reason I don't edit any more

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bluntly, it sounds like this "senior architect" fellow is a real problem for your company. It sounds like he wants a stranglehold on your development work. He does two things that taken together are destructive. He won't answer reasonable questions, AND he nitpicks other peoples' work. Oh, yeah, and he doesn't respect you enough to let you say your piece in meetings. Yowza.

Let's give him the benefit of the doubt for a moment, and assume that he is committed to helping people like you develop your skills by asking you to figure stuff out for yourselves. That job is called "teaching", and a big part of teaching is helping people think through hard questions. Pulling rank "I know that and you don't" is just plain silly as a teaching method.

The guy is toxic.

But that's not what you asked. Your manager wants you to push back when this guy overcomplicates things. It's obvious your manager respects your engineering acumen and believes you could get good things done if you could balance out this architect's theoretical perfectionism.

So you're stuck in the middle. Ouch.

For some consolation while you're working on this go read https://TheDailyWTF.com Your architect plays a starring role.

And, level with you manager. Tell him, bluntly, that this guy is hard for you to challenge (your manager surely already knows he's toxic). Ask for advice on how best to do that. Consider asking him to get support from your company's executives for your task of ignoring or simplifying this architect's advice. Make it so the two of you are working together on this problem. If you and your manager can, together, succeed at this you will learn a lot and do really good things for your career. But you have to be in it together.

If your manager can't or won't support you in this, go join that other team. No whizbang technology is worth the damage to your career and personal life caused by an unrestrained toxic bigshot. Plus you'll be on a good team and learn a lot.

Good luck and strength.

Comment: Frankly, I am not sure whether we can safely conclude from the original question that the person is toxic. Insisting on best practices or evaluating pull requests is part of the role of a senior/architect.
It looks like OP is disagreeing with the feedback, but its hard to judge who is right, since there is no technical examples given.

Comment: Seconded... this makes a lot of assumptions, twists a lot of words and is unnecessarily aggressive...

Answer (score 10):

I'm going to swing the other way and say that this Architect is being reasonable. Being an Architect is a very high position and involves understanding the best practices, the best systems and the in's and out's of the technologies in use.

> if I come with a question with two possible solutions to know his opinion, instead of sharing what he thinks is better, he would say "Did you read chapter 'x' on the book 'y' or this particular paper?". He would then preach for 5 minutes what a good software developer should know before actually giving his opinion.

Honestly, it sounds like your Architect is really annoyed by constant questions regarding the same thing. While this is a flaw on his part (Part of his job is to learn and maintain knowledge), I can understand where this comes from if people keep asking him questions that he considers trivial.

> he objects to pull requests that he hasn't approved, finding trivial faults in 50 different places quoting some theories/concepts and blocking the request

This sounds like the architect is ensuring the code that is being developed follows the principles of whatever method/solution is being applied. This can be important, because some methods only work really well if they are applied properly. E.g. there isn't much point in Object oriented coding if you just break large chunks of code into random functions because the code is getting too long.

In reality, I doubt an Architect should actually be looking at the code and approving changes like this. Usually a senior developer would fill this role because they are actively working on the code, while an architect is looking at the big picture.

> in our stand-ups, he interrupts when other people are talking and doesn't miss an opportunity to portray how smart he is

This can be pretty normal for a stand up. A stand up is a quick report on what you are doing and what is blocking you. This way anyone who might be able to assist you in overcoming an issue can step up and help. Since you given us any example scenarios, I can only assume that he is offering pointers, but doing so very poorly.

> he favours theoretical best practices over simple, functional designs despite this leading to frequent complaints from users

Same as some of the stuff above. Your architect is probably trying to make sure you conform to certain practices and methodologies to ensure the end goal of having good, readable, maintainable code is reached. Simple function designs are great and a good way of moving fast, but when you create large projects, you need to look at the big picture. A lot of theories work in theory, but fail in reality, simply because people skip steps which seem useless or redundant.

Summary:
Your Architect is probably a very technical person and also a very busy person. They don't have the time to explain everything, but because the same issues get brought up again and again, they waste time complaining instead of addressing the issue at hand.

The easiest solution is to simply trust them. If they start to rant, cut them off. Tell them you need their decision and accept it. Of course, this isn't what your manager wants.

The other way is to simply talk to them. Ask them questions like "I have solution A and solution B. Solution A is faster and easier to use. you recommended solution B. Why is that?" Engage in the conversation, have a back and forth. Once you understand why the Architect chose a certain solution or method or coding practice, you have a better chance of proposing a solution and convincing the architect that your method is better for the business. "Solution A is better despite being less sophisticated because it will only be run once a week. The redundancy in Solution B would take too long to develop and is too extensive to cover the simple task of combining excel sheets together".

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. You have brought in some good points about the other side, though there are a few things I would disagree. You made the assumption that I ask constant questions, which I do not think I do. We are not in same office and we only chat every other day. There was a pull request that was approved by another lead developer, but later blocked by him before merge. I trust his ability and let him win usually (hence my manager's comment to challenge more), but I do not agree that because you know more, you are above showing respect to others.

Comment: @rdown An architect is usually pretty high level, which means anyone involved in a project his a part of will be asking them questions. This means managers, devs, the business/customer. I know quite a few devs who would love to be able to sit down all day and code without having to worry about being disturbed. This all probably leads to the architect having a very short fuse, which isn't your fault. They need to work on that themselves.

Comment: @rdown How/when does the architect show disrespect? You mentioned interrupting during standup, which could possibly be disrespectful, but that can also be done tactfully.

Comment: @Shadowzee possible suggestion: the Architect in the scenario could (/should) automate the checking of a lot of the best practices for the language in use. Github, Bitbucket, Gitlab, etc. all support the ability of performing quality assurance, breaking, style, and more, checks when a commit is done or a pull request is made/changed. The Architect might come of as less of a prick if/when such things are automated. - Added this as something that could be suggested and might improve the answer a bit, apart from that, agree with this one more than accepted one.

Comment: @Mars I'd interpret the combination of frequent interruptions and condescending answers (plus preaching when OP just sought an opinion) as disrespect. Those things can be normal in some cultures but where I work that would definitely be interpreted as a lack of professional courtesy.

Comment: @Borgh I haven't seen any disrespect yet, so I have asked many questions that OP hasn't answered... it also didn't come across as preaching to me. It sounded more like someone who can't cut to the chase, but who states not only which to choose, but why and where to look for more info. More info than OP probably wants, but not disrespectful at all

Answer (score 1):

This question has already an accepted answer, but I would like to share my view.

I think, this is a political war between that senior architect and your manager. It’s not your war, don’t get involve.

If I was you I would have read every thing that the SA address in his answers and try my best to learn from him.If you believe he is better, then listen to him!

Answer (score -2):

Your manager hopefully doesn't want you to challenge anyone, but they want to see problems being solved in a better way. The functional issue I see is only one:

> he [senior architect, SA] favours theoretical best practices over simple, functional designs despite this leading to frequent complaints from users

In teams it all boils down to who has the decision-making power and responsibility. Ask your manager, what decisions you can make on your own. If they come back with "I want you to come up with solution together with SA" then ask who has to make the final decision. Proactively ask for an areas or parts of specification where you can make decisions on your own. Promise to consult anyone involved, but somebody has to be in charge.

Other points you raise have a lot to do with difficult personality of the SA.

Answer (score -2):

You need a team effort to deal with such behavior. You have been asked to push back, showing that you have legitimately good ideas and skills. If you don't push back you will be smothered.

If you push back, the rant from him will likely start. When he is ranting, use language that proves you are not listening. For example if his name is Bob, then when he starts going on, repeatedly say Bob Bob Bob Bob ... you need to get him to stop talking before he can hear. Then directly ask him to explain what is physically wrong with your idea.

At the same time, the manager needs to interject minor objections being made into mountains.

Keep pulling back to the core purpose of the task. The task is XYZ. Would my solution accomplish it? Any time he directs to the theoretical and starts ranting, Bob Bob Bob him and pull back to the physical.

Don't be rude. Let all the insults and nonsense about engineers should know this and that, slide. Don't get roped in but instead stick to the one point.

For reviews, has this architect produced a solidified coding style document? Continually getting 50+ blocks implies there is no formal process and he is applying his methodology when it suits.

If there is a formal code doc, then follow it. If not, work with the manager to get one. You can also look into clang-format if its purely a stylistic thing. Warning though, code style formalization meetings tend to get brutal. The end result is good though.